# How can i show array without key

Tags: php, arrays, get, show

i want show array without []=> mycod is

```
foreach ($results as  $value=>$value2){  //for array $ resullt is array        
            $array2=print_r($value2);
           return true;

       }


Array ( [0] => test [1] => test [2] => test [3] => test [4] => test)
```

Comment: read more about array. array will have key. you can print array elements by loop through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo implode("", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `print_r` then, or `var_dump` for that matter. Just set `$array2 = $value2;`

Answer (score 0):

To only echo the values you can do this:

```
foreach ($results as  $key=>$value){  //for array $ resullt is array        
      echo $value . "<br />";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not have array without keys.

you can  access array elements by looping through it and can create formatted output. like this:

```
$strOutput = "";
foreach ($results as  $value=>$value2){      
            $strOutput .= $value2 ." ";
       }
echo $strOutput;
```